# Difference between $x$ square and $x$ squared

Tags: exponentiation, square-numbers

Often i have encountered the phrases **$x$ square** and **$x$ squared** for $x^2$.

My question is: Are both the phrases correct or is any one of them incorrect. If both of them are correct, is there any difference between their meaning and their usage or are both the same is meaning and have the same usage?

Comment: In most contexts. "x square" is fine, and "x squared", while comprehensible, sounds a little weird.

Comment: I have *never* heard the phrase "*x square*" in any context, much less to represent $x^2$.  The phrase "*x squared*" although not following usual rules of grammar, is in common use in the English language to refer to the variable $x$ being raised to the power of two., a sort of shortened form of the phrase "the variable x (*which has been*) squared" which is following proper grammar rules

Comment: Of course you can say "if x is squared, then ...", but that can also be said as: "if you square x then ..."

Comment: The pythagoran theorem: "a square plus b square = c square".

Comment: A google search for the phrase "x square" in quotes returns only 496k results, and none of the top results seem to be in reference to $x^2$, meanwhile a search for the phrase "x squared" in quotes returns 4.5mil, all of the top results in reference to $x^2$.

Comment: You say potato.  I say potato.  Okay, imagine me saying it with different pronunciation.

Comment: Then I guess I'm in the minority, but math terminology evolves towards brevity, so maybe I'm ahead of my time.

Comment: @JMoravitz that's as close to an answer as anybody is going to get

Comment: To add to the confusion, I have heard "100 meters square" to refer to a square 100 meters on a side as opposed to "100 square meters" which could be $10 \times 10$ (or any equal area).

Comment: @quasi I've always heard the pythagoarean theorem as "a squared plus b squared = c squared".  I've usually heard numbers squared but for physical distances I've heard 100 meters square if the speaker is british and 100 meters squared if the speaker is american.  They are interchangeable.  I very much prefer "squared" but I'm only speaking for myself.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard it that way as well. I guess when reading written expressions quickly, I say "x-square", but for an emphasized statement, I think "x-squared" sounds more appropriate.

Comment: @fleablood One could also say "100 square meters", at least in the US.

Comment: @DavidK not of the meant a square 100 meters on each side.  Like Ross said.  100 square meters is 10 meters square or 10 meters squared.  I've heard both.  But I've never heard 7 square to mean 49.

Comment: @fleablood I missed Ross's comment. I've heard "meters square" used that way, as in, "the dimensions of the plot were 100 meters square," but I would interpret "100 meters squared" as $100\;\mathrm m^2$ rather than $(100\;\mathrm m)^2.$

Comment: Actually you may be right and it could go back to the legal but mathematically naive notion of strip areas as in yards of cloth, chains and the original definition of acre.  So 100 meters square could mean a 1 by 100 meter strip.  Frankly, if it were up to me I'd say avoid the ambiguity and *always* say "squared".  It logically makes more sense, it's unambiguous, and to my ear it just sounds right and natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $b^2 = b ⋅ b$ is called "the square of b".

It is pronounced "b squared".

The expression $b^3 = b ⋅ b ⋅ b$ is called "the cube of b".

It is pronounced "b cubed".

For more exponents, the expression (for example) $3^5 = 3 ⋅ 3 ⋅ 3 ⋅ 3 ⋅ 3 = 243$ is called the fifth power of $3$, $3$ raised to the fifth power, or $3$ to the power of $5$.

The word "raised" is usually omitted, and very often "power" as well, so $3^5$ is typically pronounced "three to the fifth" or "three to the five". Therefore, the exponentiation $b^n$ can be read as $b$ raised to the $n-th$ power, or $b$ raised to the power of $n$, or $b$ raised by the exponent of $n$, or most briefly as $b$ to the $n$.

Source

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation